# Unload Extension Autodesk.FullScreen from Forge Viewer is not working

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-bim360

Hello and thanks for taking time to read this,

we developing an App with Autodesk Forge for displaying informations related to some specific components. In this context we disabled and unloaded a few Extensions which are preLoaded by the Forge Viewer. Which is similar to this [StackOverflow -- Unload Forge Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59953285/how-do-i-unload-a-deafult-extension-in-forge-viewer).

We also want to unload the 'Autodesk.FullScreen' und purpose of our Users. https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Extensions/FullScreenExtension/

Following i added the Code we tried in Console of the Browser with the provided result:

First we let us show the loaded extensions:

```
NOP_VIEWER.getLoadedExtensions()
{Autodesk.BIM360.Minimap: l, BasicExtension: U, Autodesk.ViewCubeUi: Y, Autodesk.CompGeom: l, Autodesk.LayerManager: P, …}
Autodesk.BIM360.Minimap: l {viewer: C, globalManager: e, setGlobalManager: ƒ, onSetGlobalManager: ƒ, getWindow: ƒ, …}
Autodesk.BoxSelection: r {viewer: C, globalManager: e, setGlobalManager: ƒ, onSetGlobalManager: ƒ, getWindow: ƒ, …}
Autodesk.CompGeom: l {viewer: C, globalManager: e, setGlobalManager: ƒ, onSetGlobalManager: ƒ, getWindow: ƒ, …}
Autodesk.LayerManager: P {viewer: C, globalManager: e, setGlobalManager: ƒ, onSetGlobalManager: ƒ, getWindow: ƒ, …}
Autodesk.Measure: Pe {viewer: C, globalManager: e, setGlobalManager: ƒ, onSetGlobalManager: ƒ, getWindow: ƒ, …}
Autodesk.Section: _ {viewer: C, globalManager: e, setGlobalManager: ƒ, onSetGlobalManager: ƒ, getWindow: ƒ, …}
Autodesk.Snapping: c {viewer: C, globalManager: e, setGlobalManager: ƒ, onSetGlobalManager: ƒ, getWindow: ƒ, …}
Autodesk.ViewCubeUi: Y {viewer: C, globalManager: e, setGlobalManager: ƒ, onSetGlobalManager: ƒ, getWindow: ƒ, …}
BasicExtension: U {viewer: C, extOptions: {…}, eventArgsTypeMap: {…}, eventStreams: Array(10), events: Array(10), …}
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Here we don't the the Autodesk.FullScreen Extensions which is a bit strange. Because it is definitly in the Toolbar and useable as you can see on the attached Image in the end of this Post...

Optimistic as we are we try to unload it:

```
NOP_VIEWER.unloadExtension('Autodesk.FullScreen')
false
```

As expected we getting a false... But nevermind to be sure we check if its loaded:

```
NOP_VIEWER.getExtension('Autodesk.FullScreen')
null
```

As expected we getting a null back. But the Extension is still there and working?

So what is the difference here to the other Extensions? Is it as designed? If it so, than the Documentation is missleading here. Maybe someone has a idea? Fun Fact you can see the same behaviour regarding to the 'Autodesk.ViewerSettings' Extension [Autodesk Forge - Autodesk.ViewerSettings Extension](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Extensions/ViewerSettingsExtension/)

[Showing Taskbar with Extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BKqd.png)

Is there something different about this Extension? Can it be unloaded or is it in another Context and the complete Toolbar needs to be removed? Maybe to mention that the Button is unloaded on a Mobile Device by default. So there must be some working mechanism to unload it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post which describes how to remove toolbar buttons and when : [When to remove toolbar buttons](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/when-remove-toolbar-buttons)

You can intercept the `TOOLBAR_CREATED_EVENT` and remove the related control.

Comment: This was the missing hint. If you implement it in TypeScript be aware to make sure to cast it as ToolBar.